# How to define a host in google play games real time multiplayer?

Tags: java, android, google-play-games

I am trying to create a real-time multiplayer game using Google Play Game Services. I am trying to set one player as host.How can I achieve this in the following method-

```
@Override
public void onRoomConnected(int statusCode, Room room) 
{
   Log.d(TAG, "onRoomConnected(" + statusCode + ", " + room + ")");
    if (statusCode != GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
        Log.e(TAG, "*** Error: onRoomConnected, status " + statusCode);
        showGameError();
        return;
    }

    updateRoom(room);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it's recommended to [add a waiting room UI](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer#optional_adding_a_waiting_room_ui) which you can launch from the `RoomUpdateListener.onRoomConnected`. Use a `participant ID` as a temporary identifier for the participants and should be valid only for a particular room.

Then, as participants join and get connected, you can initiate assigning a specific user and consider the logic suggested in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20930683).

Check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yIY1zsZ2yCU) for additional insights and the sample implementation in this [GitHub post](https://github.com/playgameservices/8bitartist/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/example/eightbitartist/DrawingActivity.java) might also help.